# Footer margin - How to remove it?

Tags: html, css

Trying to figure why, when on some pages there's a huge margin (space) in the footer, see here for example

https://wrestlenation.net/misc.php?action=help&hid=8

It's only on pages where there isn't many elements on the page.

Comment: This happens because there is little content, so the main div is small, and the footer just appears under it.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for that, I thought there was some margin issue going on.

Comment: Use `html,body{min-height:100%;}` to force the `<body>` to the full window height

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Hi, that didn't seem to change anything? Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used similar code to achieve this in the past

```css
.PAGE-CONTENT-CONTAINER {
 position: relative; /*positions relative to its normal position*/
  min-height: 100vh; /* 1vh is Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*/
  padding-bottom: 60px; /* Should be equal to the height of your footer */
}

.FOOTER {
  width: 100%; /* self explanatory */
  position: absolute; /*The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element*/
  bottom: 0PX; /*property affects the vertical position of a positioned element*/
}
```

Comment: Brilliant,  min-height: 100vh on container worked like a charm.